# MySQL Group by column and then extract each group into a .csv file?

Tags: mysql, csv

For example, say I have a table (say the columns are [letter, color, number]):

```
a|green |2
b|blue  |3
a|red   |3
a|blue  |4
b|yellow|1
c|red   |9
c|blue  |5
```

First, I want to group/order them by the first column so that it's:

```
a|green |2
a|red   |3
a|blue  |4
b|blue  |3
b|yellow|1
c|red   |9
c|blue  |5
```

Finally, I want to extract each group into distinct .csv files:

```
a.csv
a|green |2
a|red   |3
a|blue  |4

b.csv
b|blue  |3
b|yellow|1


c.csv
c|red   |9
c|blue  |5
```

Thanks!

edit: how do I preserve the new lines? It's not showing up correctly
edit2: thank you for fixing it!

Comment: Your first step is just ordering them, not grouping them.

Comment: Use Ctl-k or the `{}` code tool to mark code that should be displayed literally.

Comment: yup! I just realized that (referring to the very first comment)

Comment: This would be trivial using PHP (or other server language)

Comment: Is there an example of how to do in PHP? (I am unfamiliar with PHP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE ...` for each value of the first column.

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE 'a.csv'
FROM yourTable
WHERE col1 = 'a';

SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE 'b.csv'
FROM yourTable
WHERE col1 = 'b';
```

and so on.

If you need to do this dynamically for an unknown set of values, you can write a stored procedure that loops over the result of

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1
FROM yourTable;
```

It will need to generate dynamic SQL with the appropriate filename in it for each query, using `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you explain the second one into more detail please? I have a huge dataset with many distinct column values

Comment: I think I described it pretty clearly. I'm not sure how to go further without actually writing the code.